# Does anybody know if FuzzyWuzzy work inside IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, fuzzywuzzy

Does the FuzzyWuzzy module work in IronPython?

I am trying to use it inside another application that implements IronPython.

Comment: Might be faster to just try it than posting here...

Comment: I have tried loading the module inside the software where I write python scripts it didn't work. But I can't get my IT department to install FuzzyWuzzy unless I already know it will work with IronPython2.7

Comment: When you say "tried but didn't work", that's a totally different question. Then it's not just "does it work?" but "how can I make it work?". You should read [ask], then [edit] your question. Add the code you've tried as a [mcve], including any errors and stack traces. That would be a much better question than a vague "does this work?" that looks like you didn't even try solving it for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: import sys
pyt_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib'
sys.path.append(pyt_path)

Comment: The above code snippit works for importing this into the programming environment I am using